# Approval History related list not showing

Tags: approval-process, approval-history

I'm logged in as an admin, and can't figure out why the Approval History related list isn't showing.

The approval process is on the correct custom object, and the page layout that contains the relates list is definitely assigned to my profile.

Is there anything else that would prevent this related list from showing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you checking this in Classic or LEX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this component just wasn't on the lightning app page.